When you drop an index, what could be dependent on it to need CASCADE?
If we use
DROP INDEX xxx

What could the index have which would be considered dependent?
I.e. if we did
DROP INDEX xxxx CASCADE

What additional objects might be dropped?  Will it for example drop the table it was the index on?  If not what could it drop?
We are trying to decide if we should be using CASCADE or not.

Great question! However I can't find a single example of the usage of CASCADE. I was expecting this to work on unique and primary key constraints, but that doesn't work: You have to drop the constraint. And since a table isn't dependent on an index, that wouldn't do anything at all. CASCADE is supported since version 7.3 but it looks like this was done just because all DROP statements should support CASCADE. I don't think it does anything. I never used it and will not use it either because you don't know what's going to change in the future.

What is the index definition? Add as text update to question text.
